# Quiero solucionar el problema de la etiqueta FIXED en dispositivos IOS

Tags: javascript, css

En este ejemplo básico que he creado: https://flowingbytes.com/REVEALER_DUDA/ veis que hay un scroll que mantiene una imagen fija durante el mismo. (la imagen de los tejados y las casas). Esto lo consigo asi:

```
<!-- START CREATIVITY CONTENT -->
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
        <div id="creativity" style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden; background-image: url('images/fondo.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-attachment: fixed;">
            <!-- Enlace con Imagen del marco -->
            <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" id="frameLink" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 300px; height: 600px; cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="images/marco.png" alt="Marco" id="frameImage" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- END CREATIVITY CONTENT -->
```

con la propiedad background-attachment: fixed y como se puede ver, deja fija la imagen mientras se hace el scroll. Esto a mi particularmente me funciona tanto en desktop como en movil android, pero al parecer . . . en dispositivos iOS no funciona porque segun https://caniuse.com/?search=fixed la etiqueta fixed se lleva mal con estos dispositivos y la cosa es que falla. Hay alguna etiqueta, o modo de hacer lo mismo sin usar background-attachment: fixed y que produzca el mismo ejemplo????